# How to setup zsh-users/antigen with nix-env (non NixOS)?

Tags: zsh, nix, zshrc

I installed antigen with `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.antigen`. After that, I have to source the `antigen.zsh` file into `.zshrc` but how do I get this file path from nix? Note that I am using macOS with `nix-env`. One way that I found is to get it from `.nix-profile/shared/antigen/antigen.zsh` but is it the best way to do it; if so, does it have any cons? Also, is there a `$(brew --prefix)` version for nix?

Comment: this might be helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541551/how-can-i-reference-the-store-path-of-a-nix-package